# Is luaotfload package broken?

Tags: texlive, luaotfload

Today's (2019-02-09) tlmgr update of TeXLive 2018 (on Linux) broke my project (around twelve hundred pages in several books typeset with LuaLaTeX using Adobe Garamond Pro) severely — almost all the pages were modified badly in huge measure. I had to restore the package luaotfload to its previous version (from broken version 49978):

```
tlmgr restore luaotfload 49747
```

After that the books compiled OK again.

**Edited later**
Seems the broken version of luaotdload causes fontspec `LetterSpace` instruction to be ignored.

Here comes some MWE (might be perhaps more minimalized, this is a quick extract of settings — obviously modified to extreme to display the problem — in my project (the text of which I do not own the copyright so I cannot use it here, but this should be enough)):

```
%%%! LuaLaTeX

\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{
  Ligatures = { TeX, Common, },
  ItalicFeatures = { LetterSpace = 10 },
  Numbers = { Proportional },
}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{czech}
\setotherlanguage{esperanto}
\setmainfont[BoldFont={agaramondprosemibold}]{adobegaramondpro}
\usepackage[
  protrusion = true,
  expansion = true,
  tracking = true,
  factor = 800,
  stretch = 15,
  shrink = 15
]{microtype}

\begin{document}


\textit{Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy.}

{
\addfontfeature{ LetterSpace = 15 }
Some text with huge spacing
}


\end{document}
```

Here is the result (correct is with the previous version of luaotdfload (49747), bad with the current version (49978):
[image]

**Edit:** the same problem occurs with Libertinus, just use:

```
\setmainfont{libertinusserif}
```

Even shorter MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[LetterSpace = 150]{Latin Modern Roman}

\begin{document}
Some text with huge spacing
\end{document}
```

Comment: No need for TeX Live people to read this. As you may read in the manual the home of luaotfload is https://github.com/u-fischer/luaotfload (i.e. there's an issue tracker and not a mailing list…).

Comment: I can understand your frustration, but please note that this site is neither the place to report bugs in packages nor a place to rant about the development of packages. As such I feel that while this question could certainly go somewhere (for example with a short document that reproduces undesirable behaviour) in its current form it is off-topic here.

Comment: Btw: It's hard to answer the question whether the package is broken without seeing how you use it. Maybe it's a simple user error that happened to work earlier. So a MWE that compiles with the old version and is messed up with the new one would be very helpful for us to help you.

Comment: -1: (aside from the unnecessary rude language) Test the stuff before you update, if it is that important. This is true for free and commercial software.

Comment: On a related note, please remember that LaTeX development is almost exclusively driven by volunteers (actually `luaotfload` might be a slight exception what with PRAGMA ADE driving development). Even though many LaTeX projects have extensive test suites, it simply cannot be guaranteed that an update will not introduce even the slightest change. In those cases developers rely on users reporting issues that arise from changes. That's why almost any package on CTAN has a documentation that explains how to report bugs. Vaguely complaining about issues on a forum isn't going to help anyone.

Comment: I fully understand that you are really angry about that bug. Happend to me years ago as well: all of a sudden project no longer compiled and the change even was deliberately. And I don't share the view that you have to test every update of texlive beforehand. I voted to reopen.

Comment: I added another shorter version of the MWE with fonts that should be available everywhere. The example works as expected with XeLaTeX but fails to work on LuaLaTeX. If you could confirm that it is the same issue that might help to make things more compact. (Feel free to roll back the edit if you think it does not help to clarify the question.)

Comment: @moewe Yes it appears to be the same problem. Thanks for the real M in MWE.

Comment: I have also encountered this issue today, and the suggested restore fixed it for me.