# microtype: \texls has no effect

Tags: luatex, fontspec, microtype, luaotfload

I use `microtype's` `\textls` in combination with `fontspec` to change the tracking of text, and until recently, this worked as it should. Recently, it seems to have stopped to work with fonts other than Latin Modern.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\setmainfont{Georgia}
\begin{document}

\textls[-100]{Bereits hier zeichnen sich erste Widersprüche ab; als regelrecht absurd erscheint angesichts der angeblichen Friedfertigkeit der Utopier aber dann die große Zahl von sehr wohl zulässigen Kriegsgründen: Die Bewohner Utopias stehen befreundeten Völkern im Kriegsfall bei und führen für sie sogar Rachefeldzüge, ebenso befreien sie unterdrückte Völker von Tyrannen.}

\textls[100]{Bereits hier zeichnen sich erste Widersprüche ab; als regelrecht absurd erscheint angesichts der angeblichen Friedfertigkeit der Utopier aber dann die große Zahl von sehr wohl zulässigen Kriegsgründen: Die Bewohner Utopias stehen befreundeten Völkern im Kriegsfall bei und führen für sie sogar Rachefeldzüge, ebenso befreien sie unterdrückte Völker von Tyrannen.}

Bereits hier zeichnen sich erste Widersprüche ab; als regelrecht absurd erscheint angesichts der angeblichen Friedfertigkeit der Utopier aber dann die große Zahl von sehr wohl zulässigen Kriegsgründen: Die Bewohner Utopias stehen befreundeten Völkern im Kriegsfall bei und führen für sie sogar Rachefeldzüge, ebenso befreien sie unterdrückte Völker von Tyrannen.

\end{document}
```

If I use Georgia, the `\textls` command has no effect and the three paragraphs turn out identical, even with these rather extreme values. If I comment the `\setmainfont` out, it works normally.

I suspect this is due to a recent update to some font-loading package, but I have no idea who the culprit is.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/474046/35864, https://github.com/u-fischer/luaotfload/issues/38 and just from this morning https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.text.tex/7SUOz0GP88Q/R9WyF89xAgAJ

Comment: With `luaotfload-letterspace.lua` from https://github.com/u-fischer/luaotfload/pull/39 the example throws an error `microtype.lua:145: attempt to call a nil 
value (field 'warning')` but the output seems to be OK again. (I just dropped the `.lua` into a test folder, not sure if I did something wrong that might have caused the error).

Comment: Mhhh, seems as though my `attempt to call a nil value (field 'warning')` error is related to the way `microtype` issues warnings: It doesn't work if `luatexbase` is not loaded, since `luatexbase.provides_module` does not return log, warn and error functions otherwise. The fact that `luaotfload`'s letter space handling changes with the new file seems to take `microtype` into a different branch where a warning is issued (and that fails since the warning function is not provided).

Comment: @moewe Thanks, using `luaotfload-letterspace.lua` did the trick. Sorry for not paying better attention that this issue was already brought up.

Comment: I see there's an update for `luaotfload`. So is this considered fixed?

Comment: The new version of `luaotfload` seems to break `microtype`. Is this known?

Comment: To  answer my own question: This has now been reported. The problem seems to be on the side of `microtype`. `\usepackage{luatexbase}` fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do it without `microtype`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{texgyreschola}[
Extension = .otf,
UprightFont = *-regular,
ItalicFont = *-italic,
BoldFont = *-bold,
BoldItalicFont = *-bolditalic,
]
\newcommand\textls[2][0]{{\letterspacefont\lsfont\font#1\lsfont#2}}
\begin{document}

\textls[-100]{Bereits hier zeichnen sich erste Widersprüche ab; als regelrecht absurd erscheint angesichts der angeblichen Friedfertigkeit der Utopier aber dann die große Zahl von sehr wohl zulässigen Kriegsgründen: Die Bewohner Utopias stehen befreundeten Völkern im Kriegsfall bei und führen für sie sogar Rachefeldzüge, ebenso befreien sie unterdrückte Völker von Tyrannen.}

\textls[100]{Bereits hier zeichnen sich erste Widersprüche ab; als regelrecht absurd erscheint angesichts der angeblichen Friedfertigkeit der Utopier aber dann die große Zahl von sehr wohl zulässigen Kriegsgründen: Die Bewohner Utopias stehen befreundeten Völkern im Kriegsfall bei und führen für sie sogar Rachefeldzüge, ebenso befreien sie unterdrückte Völker von Tyrannen.}

Bereits hier zeichnen sich erste Widersprüche ab; als regelrecht absurd erscheint angesichts der angeblichen Friedfertigkeit der Utopier aber dann die große Zahl von sehr wohl zulässigen Kriegsgründen: Die Bewohner Utopias stehen befreundeten Völkern im Kriegsfall bei und führen für sie sogar Rachefeldzüge, ebenso befreien sie unterdrückte Völker von Tyrannen.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I actually don't want to miss out on `microtype`.

Comment: @Simifilm Why not?  What does it provide that can't be done with plain LuaLaTeX?  In my experience `microtype` is actually harmful because it hooks into LaTeX's font selection mechanism, which can break other packages.